# Cambiar ultimo caracter de string en Python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero cambiar el ultimo carácter de una cadena, siempre que la longitud de la cadena es igual a 4.
Si la longitud de la cadena es igual a 4, entonces cambiar el ultimo caracter de acuerdo con el criterio siguiente:

Si termina en "a" se debe cambiar por 1,
Si termina en "b" se debe cambiar por 2,
Si termina en "c" se debe cambiar por 3,
El resultado debe ser:

```
codigo - resultado
p10      p10
a01      a01
a01a     a011
b10b     b102
c33      c33
d12c     d123
```

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "hacedme las tareas de clase" no son bienvenidas en SOes si no se demuestra un esfuerzo previo por resolverlas. Sólo has puesto el requirimiento, ¿qué has intentado? te recomiendo que leas el [tour] de bienvenida y entiendas qué es un [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Espero te sea util, saludos!

```
#Pregunta un codigo y lo almacena en una variable#
codigoIngresado = input("Ingrese su codigo: ")


def convertir(codigo):
    #Contamos cuantas letras tiene el codigo ingresado#
    cantidad_de_letras = len(codigo)

    if (cantidad_de_letras == 4):

    #Obtenemos la ultima letra del codigo y la compramos con la letra a#
        if codigo[cantidad_de_letras-1] == "a":

        #Cortamos el codigo y nos quedamos solo con las primeras 3 letras#
            resultado = codigo[0:3]
            """A las 3 primeras letras que nos quedaron le concatenamos(agregamos/sumamos) 
            el 1"""
            resultado = resultado+"1"
            print("El resultado es: " + resultado)

        #Lo mismo con los demas casos#

        elif codigo[cantidad_de_letras-1] == "b":
            resultado = codigo[0:3]
            resultado = resultado+"2"
            print("El resultado es: " + resultado)

        elif codigo[cantidad_de_letras-1] == "c":
            resultado = codigo[0:3]
            resultado = resultado+"3"
            print("El resultado es: " + resultado)
    else:
        print(codigo)
        return

#Llama la funcion convertir y le pasa como parametro la variable codigoIngresado#

convertir(codigoIngresado)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta rápida. Pregunta: Si tengo un data frame y requiero crear una nueva columna con el resultado del cambio del ultimo caracter, cual sería el codigo?. Agradezco tu amable respuesta.

Comment: Por favor evita responder este tipo de preguntas, el OP no muestra lo que ha intentado, más que ayudar lo perjudicas. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por ágil respuesta. Lo que requiero ahora es crear una nueva columna con los datos de resultado. Para ello utilizando tu respuesta, llamo la función con apply, pero el resultado es none. El codigo utilizado es: